# Alternative Applications of Portfolio Optimization

Tags: multiple-regression, optimization

What other statistical optimizations in the natural and social sciences require the maximization of the difference between the mean and the variance?

In other words have an objective function (maximand) like:
Mean-(weight)*Variance
-or-
Mean-(weight)*MSE   i.e. regression of a constant on variables.

I read on the internet of optimal traffic routing and thought of optimal allocation of crops for a given amount of land. Can anyone think of others?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to maximize the "difference between the mean and variance" as they are in incommensurable units... for instance, mean length may be in centimetres but its variance would be in square centimetres. Switching your unit system to metres will change the minimum.

Comment: It isn't clear to me that this is really a statistical question, but I would think a lot of areas where people are trying to optimize outcomes you want high means (good outcomes) with low variance.  Percent cured (Bernoulli with $p=1$ & variance $= 0$) could be an example.

Comment: This is very much a statistical problem, surely maximizing or minimizing a weighted average of the moments of an objective function derived from weightings on a set of probability distributions is a statistical problem? It also happens to be an unsolved statistical optimization in the sense that there is no generally accepted method for mitigating the effect of estimation error on the extra sample values obtained for the objective function. Quant finance modelers are unlikely to know of applications outside finance.

Answer (score 1):

The author of a paper I recently read seems to think that portfolio management can be used in many different areas:

> Portfolio Management methods are significant because, besides finance, they can also be applied in economics, industry sector allocation, computer hardware and software technologies, web design, teaching,  planning  health  promotion  programs, and other disciplines. [7] [8].

-- Portfolio of Automated Trading Systems: Complexity and Learning Set Size Issues (Sarunas Raudys 2013).

Here is what he cites in support of his statement:

[7]   M.  Jeffery  and  I.  Leliveld,  “Best  practices  in  IT  portfolio,” MIT  Sloan Manag.  Rev., vol. 45, no. 3, pp. 41–49, 2004.

[8]   D.  M.  Berwick,  “Disseminating  innovations  in  health  care,”
J.  Amer. Med. Assoc., vol. 289, no. 15, pp. 1969–1975,  2003.